# can shorthand method applied in foreach?

Tags: php, foreach, shorthand

So I found this SHORTHAND PHP methods on google like:

```
if(isset($a))
{
    $a = TRUE;
}
else
{
    $a = FALSE;
}
```

can be converted on a single line statement as:
`$a = isset($a) ? TRUE : FALSE;`

which is working correctly and I have a script which I fail to apply the **SHORT HAND** method.

PHP:

```
<?php
$letters = ['1' => 'A', '2' => 'B', '3' => 'C'];

$data['LETTER'] = "";

foreach($letters as $id => $letter)
{
    $data['LETTER'] .= "<option value=$id>".$letter."</option>";
}

$html = file_get_contents('test.html');

echo $html = str_replace(array_keys($data),array_values($data),$html);
?>
```

I've end using with this **SHORTHAND METHOD** which won't work at all

`$data['LETTER'] = foreach($letters as $id => $letter) ? "<option value=$id>".$letter."</option>" : "";`

is there any possibilities to shorten the script above?

Comment: Your `$a = '1' ? TRUE : FALSE;` is not same as your condition: `'1'` will always be true and no comparison with `$a` will be done

Comment: @AlmaDo sorry I updated my question

Answer (score 3):

There is no shorthand method for `foreach`, however you can achieve it with [`array_map`](http://php.net/array_map):

```
$data['LETTER'] = implode(array_map(function($id, $letter){ return "<option value=$id>".$letter."</option>"; }, $letters));
```

Comment: ...which is, actually, almost same as `foreach` :p

Comment: But not a `foreach`.. so OP's answer is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a function like below

```
function getOptions($letters){
    $opt = "";
    foreach($letters as $id => $letter){
        $opt .= "<option value=$id>".$letter."</option>";
    }

    return $opt;
}

$letters = array('1' => 'A', '2' => 'B', '3' => 'C');

$data['LETTER'] = getOptions($letters);
```

In other way

```
foreach($letters as $id => $letter):
    $data['LETTER'] .= "<option value=$id>".$letter."</option>";
endforeach;
```

Comment: uhmmmm you just put it on the `function` :(

Comment: is there a alternate way that I would not include `$opt = "";` in the script?

Comment: no you have to assign a variable to concat. anyway you can use `foreach: endforeach;` to remove `{ }`

Comment: but this is shorter way `foreach($letters as $id => $letter) $data['LETTER'] .= "<option value=$id>".$letter."</option>";`

Comment: ok then use it like
`foreach($letters as $id => $letter):  $data['LETTER'] .= "<option value=$id>".$letter."</option>"; endforeach;`

Comment: is it optional to put `endforeach` ?

Comment: no it is to end the loop; see foreach here http://designerfoo.com/php-shorthand-php-alternative-alternate-syntax-a-quickie.html